# Sorting Opportunity Line Item based on SortOrder Standard field In Report

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-report-type

I want to create a report on  Opportunity Line Item which sort Opportunity Line Item based on Standard SortOrder field.

I am not able to see Standard SortOrder field in report.

Also, I am not able to create formula field in Opportunity Line Item Object which display the value of Standard SortOrder field.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach:

1. Create a custom report type on Opportunities with or without Products `Setup | Create | Custom Report Type`
2. `SortOrder` appears as a field that can be used on the report
3. Add lookup fields from `Products` -> `PricebookEntry` -> `Product2` as needed.